Automaton rendering/state issue
I'm working on sort of automaton where there is one red with "state = 2" square which checks neighboring squares in order up, left, down, right and if one of them is has "state = 0" it will change its to "state = 2" and their state will change to 1. The issue is, when the red square is "going" left and up it doesn't show up. Also when i changed the code to render at the begging of the update function of squares class it looked like there were 2 squares that had "state = 2".
grid_size = 50
updated = False

class squares:
    def __init__(self,position,state = 0):
        self.position = position
        self.state = state
        self.operation_done = False
    def change_state(self):
        self.state = 2
    def update(self):
        global updated
        
        if not updated:
            if self.state == 2:
                self.operation_done =False
                if self.position[1] - grid_size >= 0 and not self.operation_done:
                    up = (self.position[0], self.position[1] - grid_size)
                    neighbor_up = squares_dict[up]
                    if neighbor_up.state == 0:
                        neighbor_up.change_state()
                        self.operation_done = True
                        self.state = 1
                        updated = True
                if self.position[0] - grid_size >= 0 and not self.operation_done: 
                    left = (self.position[0] - grid_size, self.position[1])
                    neighbor_left = squares_dict[left]
                    if neighbor_left.state == 0:
                        neighbor_left.change_state()
                        self.operation_done = True
                        self.state = 1
                        updated = True
                if self.position[1] + grid_size <= 450 and not self.operation_done: 
                    down = (self.position[0], self.position[1] + grid_size)
                    neighbor_down = squares_dict[down]
                    if neighbor_down.state == 0:
                        neighbor_down.change_state()
                        self.operation_done = True
                        self.state = 1
                        updated = True
                if self.position[0] + grid_size <= 450 and not self.operation_done: 
                    right = (self.position[0] + grid_size, self.position[1])
                    neighbor_right = squares_dict[right]
                    if neighbor_right.state == 0:
                        neighbor_right.change_state()
                        self.operation_done = True
                        self.state = 1
                        updated = True
                        
        if self.state == 2:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen_display,(255,0,0), (*self.position,grid_size,grid_size))
        elif self.state == 1:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen_display,(255,255,255), (*self.position,grid_size,grid_size))
        elif self.state == 0:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen_display,(0,0,0), (*self.position,grid_size,grid_size))


I have no idea whats the issue as it works right when it "goes" right and down.

There's not really enough information to answer.  What is squares_dict, how is it set-up ?

I think it would help if you define your state-transitions on how the state of "this" cell changes depending on its current state, and that of its neighbours. Having "this" cell change its neighbour's state makes it much more complex.  You need to separate the current set of states from the next set of states.  Otherwise you are checking neighbour states when they they might have already changed in this update phase in the previous row.

I think the issue is that your code is advancing the state of the square while it's still processing the world.  So say you update the east-neighbour, but the very next cell to process is x + 1, and the value of the state has just been reset!
You need to keep the "current state" and the "next, calculated state" separate.
What I have implemented below is keeping two states, self.state and self.next_state.  As the update-algorithm proceeds through the grid, tests are made on self.state but changes stored in self.next_state.  Once the entire grid-world is processed, then squares can switch to the next state.
I had to guess at what your program was supposed to do, maybe I got those parts wrong.  Apologies in advance.

import pygame
import random

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH  = 500    
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500

UPDATE_MILLIS = 1200 # time between updates
GRID_CELLS = 10      # N x N sized world-grid
GRID_SIZE = 50       # How biug cells are drawn in the window

class Square:
    def __init__(self,position,state = 0):
        self.position = position      # ( column, row ) position in the world grid
        self.state    = state         # Current state used for calculations
        self.next_state = state       # The next state we become
        # References to our neighbours, with grid wrap-around
        self.north = None
        self.east  = None
        self.south = None
        self.west  = None

    def map_neighbours( self, world_grid, grid_width, grid_height ):
        """ Link references to other cells in the grid """
        x, y = self.position
        # NORTH
        if ( y == 0 ):
            self.north = world_grid[grid_height-1][x]   # wrap-around top->bottom
        else:
            self.north = world_grid[y-1][x]
        # EAST
        if ( x == grid_width-1 ):
            self.east = world_grid[y][0]
        else:
            self.east = world_grid[y][x+1]
        # SOUTH
        if ( y == grid_height-1 ):
            self.south = world_grid[0][x]
        else:
            self.south = world_grid[y+1][x]  
        # WEST
        if ( x == 0 ):
            self.west = world_grid[y][grid_width-1]
        else:
            self.west = world_grid[y][x-1]

    def update(self):
        # Deternime the next state.
        #     If I am state==2, and my neighbour is state==0 -> switch to state:=1
        neighbours = [ self.north, self.east, self.south, self.west ]
        for neighbour in neighbours:
            if ( self.state == 2 and neighbour.state == 0 ):
                self.next_state = 1
                neighbour.next_state = 2 # TODO: re-write in terms of "my" state, don't change neighbour, it should change itself

    def advance_state( self ):
        """ Move to the target state """
        self.state = self.next_state

    def __str__( self ):
        s = "Square at (%3d,%3d) state=%d" % ( self.position[0], self.position[1], self.state )
        return s

    def draw( self, surface ):
        if self.state == 2:
            colour = (255,0,0)
        elif self.state == 1:
            colour = (255,255,255)
        elif self.state == 0:
            colour = (0,0,0)
        else:
            colour = (0,255,255)  # error, should not happen

        x,y = self.position
        pygame.draw.rect( surface, colour, (x*GRID_SIZE, y*GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE ) )




###
### MAIN
###
pygame.init()
window  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), pygame.HWSURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption("Squares")


# Define some Squares in a World
world_grid = []
for y in range( GRID_CELLS ):
    world_grid.append( [] )  # empty row
    for x in range( GRID_CELLS ):
        position = ( x, y ) 
        state = random.randint( 0, 2 )
        world_grid[y].append( Square( position, state ) )
        #print( "Added Square: " + str( world_grid[y][-1] ) )

# we can't find our neighbours until all cells are filled
for y in range( GRID_CELLS ):
    for x in range( GRID_CELLS ):
        world_grid[y][x].map_neighbours( world_grid, GRID_CELLS, GRID_CELLS )


# Main loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
next_update = pygame.time.get_ticks() + UPDATE_MILLIS  # time in future to update states
running = True
while running:
    time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            running = False

    # Update the state-transition algorithm every period
    if ( time_now > next_update ):
        next_update = time_now + UPDATE_MILLIS  # reschedule next update
        # Do the update
        for y_row in world_grid:
            for sq in y_row:
                sq.update()     # calculate all the next states
        for y_row in world_grid:
            for sq in y_row:
                sq.advance_state()   # now calc is done, switch to new state (if any)

    # Draw and update the world_grid
    for y_row in world_grid:
        for sq in y_row:
            sq.draw( window )

    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()

